# xslt 1.0 sorting when grouping

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

Last time I had some problems with grouping on xslt 1.0. Now I've faced another problem with sorting. Here is some code.

**XML**

```
<Development>
  <PlotTypes> 
    <Apartments>     
      <Building>             
        <PlotType Phase="1" />   
        <PlotType Phase="2" />         
      </Building>
    </Apartments>
  </PlotTypes>
  <Phases>
    <Phase ContentID="40514" PhaseCode="1" Title="Properties available to move in" SortOrder="2" />
    <Phase ContentID="40515" PhaseCode="2" Title="test" SortOrder="1" />
  </Phases>
</Development>
```

And here is **XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name ="phase" match="//PlotType" use="@Phase"/>
  <xsl:template match="Development">
    <xsl:for-each select="//PlotType[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('phase',@Phase)[1])]">
      <xsl:sort select="//Phase[@PhaseCode=@Phase]/@SortOrder" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:variable select="@Phase" name="groupedPhase"/>
              Phase - <xsl:value-of  select="@Phase"/><br/>
              Phase Sort order -  <xsl:value-of select="//Phase[@PhaseCode=$groupedPhase]/@SortOrder"/><br/>                
       <xsl:value-of select="//Phase[@PhaseCode=$groupedPhase]/@Title"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I need to make this final result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
              Phase - 2<br/>
              Phase Sort order -  2<br/>
<h3>test</h3>
              Phase - 1<br/>
              Phase Sort order -  1<br/>
<h3>Properties available to move in</h3>
```

But when I use such sorting `<xsl:sort select="//Phase[@PhaseCode=@Phase]/@SortOrder"...` it doesn't work.

Comment: Why does your expected output look so clumsy? Won't you like it to be a proper XML? And I don't think you really need some grouping to get such output from that input.. or may be you've not posted complete input sample..

Comment: @LingamurthyCS I need just to make grouping to be sorted by `//Phase/@SortOrder` Clumsyness is just for checking if sorting works

Comment: Can you explain about how do you want the sorting to be done. I couldn't figure out the logic

Comment: @LingamurthyCS ok Ill try. On initial xml we can see that 2 plottypes have attribute Phase - this is grouping condition, so if there 3 plottypes with two of them having phase=1 and one of them phase=1 result will be like `<phase code="1"><plottype id="A"/><plottype id="B"></phase><phase code="2"><plottype id="C"/></phase>`

Comment: @LingamurthyCS But I need not only group, but sort either. And to understand how to sort I need to look the `SortOrder` attribute in `Phase` element.

Comment: That's my confusion.. Your `PlotType` with `Phase=1` relates to `SortOrder=2` of `Phase`.. But your expected output shows `SortOrder=1`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a second key

```
<xsl:key name="phase-by-code" match="Phases/Phase" use="@PhaseCode"/>
```

then use

```
<xsl:sort select="key('phase-by-code', @Phase)/@SortOrder" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
```

for your sort.